# Custom Navbar - different image on diffrent scene

Tags: react-native

I am new in react native and I have problem. 
In my application a have 3 scenes and custom navbar. I need diffrent image on different scene. If I only change background it's work perfect, but I need more its mean image

//router.js

```
<Scene key="root" navBar={Navbar} drawer contentComponent={Drawer}>
          <Scene key="home" component={Home} initial={true} hideNavBar={true} />
          <Scene key="op" ref="Op" component={Op} 
            navigationBarStyle = {styles.sceneOp} 
            />
          <Scene key="about" component={About} 
            navigationBarStyle = {styles.sceneAbout} 
            />

        </Scene>
...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sceneOp: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },
  sceneAbout: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  }
});
```

//navbar.js - in this file, I need that my dynamicLogo was props like navigationBarStyle. How to do this?

```
  render() {

    let dynamicLogo = navStyle.assets.img;

    return (
      <View style={styles.outerContainer, this.props.navigationBarStyle}>
        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              Actions.drawerOpen();
            }}
            style={styles.sideElementContainer}
          >
            <Image style={styles.burger} source={require('../assets/burger-icon.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
            <Image style={styles.logo} source={dynamicLogo} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.sideElementContainer} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using renderTitle

//Routers.js

```
<Scene key="root" navBar={Navbar} drawer contentComponent={Drawer}>
          <Scene key="home" component={Home} initial={true} hideNavBar={true} />
          <Scene key="op" ref="Op" component={Op} 
            navigationBarStyle = {styles.sceneOp} 
            renderTitle={navImage.imgExto}
            />
          <Scene key="about" component={About} 
            navigationBarStyle = {styles.sceneAbout} 
            renderTitle={navImage.imgMe}
            />
        </Scene>
...
const navImage = {
  imgExto: require('./assets/e-logo.png'),
  imgMe: require('./assets/m-logo.png'),
};
```